# Can somebody please help me with the correct name of this

Tags: c#, android, oop

I am a programming beginner and I have a code snippet like below

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, Android.Hardware.ISensorEventListener
{
    private SensorManager _senMan;
    float lightSensorValue;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        _senMan = (SensorManager)GetSystemService (Context.SensorService);
        Sensor sen = _senMan.GetDefaultSensor (SensorType.Light);
        _senMan.RegisterListener (this, sen, Android.Hardware.SensorDelay.Game);
```

How do I call `_senMan` is it an object or a type or any other. My another question is what are the tasks that are happening in `senMan = (SensorManager)GetSystemService (Context.SensorService);` and `Sensor sen = _senMan.GetDefaultSensor (SensorType.Light);` How do we call them in a professional way.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, and you have more than one of them. Have you read the documentation for those methods? What confuses you about them? What is "Unprofessional" about the current way they are being called?

Answer (score 1):

`_senMan` is a *variable* of type `SensorManager`.

`_senMan = (SensorManager)GetSystemService (Context.SensorService);` is an *invocation* of *method* `GetSystemService`, passing the *value* of `Context.SensorService` as a *parameter*. The result of the method invocation is *cast* to type `SensorManager`.

After executing this line of code, *variable* `_senMan` references an *object* of type `SensorManager`.

`Sensor sen = _senMan.GetDefaultSensor (SensorType.Light);` is a short hand for

```
Sensor sen;
sen = _senMan.GetDefaultSensor (SensorType.Light);
```

The first is a *variable declaration*, the second an *invocation* of the `GetDefaultSensor` *method* of the object referenced by variable *_senMan*.

Comment: What is the object here, its `_sen` isnt it